# Exporting 3D models with assimp without re-indexing vertices

Tags: 3d, vertex, assimp

I'm using assimp.net to export my 3d models. assimp will re-index vertexes in exported model! I need previous order of indexes. is there any way to save previous indexes in exported model?

exporting code :

```
using (var asmpCntx = new AssimpContext())
    {
        LogStream.IsVerboseLoggingEnabled = true;
        using (var pipe = new LogPipe(_logStore))
        {
           return asmpCntx.ExportFile(_raw, "MyExportedFile.obj", "obj");
        }
    }
```

expected order :

> 130921 vertex positions
>
> v -0.111804 -0.257020 0.282297
>
> v -0.110387 -0.261969 0.278314
>
> v -0.103693 -0.262174 0.281221
>
> v -0.105030 -0.257238 0.285222
>
> v -0.106187 0.409742 0.238732
>
> v -0.106169 0.403559 0.240970
>
> v -0.100297 0.403623 0.242419
>
> v -0.100294 0.409780 0.240066
>
> v -0.585048 -0.776799 -0.674764
>
> v -0.588571 -0.779106 -0.672874
>
> v -0.584674 -0.779821 -0.668612
>
> v -0.581676 -0.777379 -0.670708
>
> v -0.064894 -0.808259 -0.292862
>
> v -0.065003 -0.813085 -0.296292
>
> v -0.056978 -0.813406 -0.295237
>
> v -0.056888 -0.808645 -0.291699
>
> ...
>
> f 1/1/1 2/2/2 3/3/3 4/4/4
>
> f 5/5/5 6/6/6 7/7/7 8/8/8
>
> f 9/9/9 10/10/10 11/11/11 12/12/12
>
> f 13/13/13 14/14/14 15/15/15 16/16/16
>
> f 17/17/17 18/18/18 19/19/19 20/20/20
>
> f 21/21/21 22/22/22 23/23/23 24/24/24
>
> f 25/25/25 26/26/26 27/27/27 28/28/28
>
> f 29/29/29 30/30/30 31/31/31 32/32/32
>
> f 33/33/33 34/34/34 35/35/35 36/36/36
>
> f 37/37/37 38/38/38 39/39/39 40/40/40
>
> f 41/41/41 42/42/42 43/43/43 44/44/44
>
> f 45/45/45 46/46/46 47/47/47 48/48/48
>
> f 49/49/49 50/50/50 51/51/51 52/52/52
>
> f 53/53/53 54/54/54 55/55/55 56/56/56
>
> f 57/57/57 58/58/58 59/59/59 60/60/60
>
> f 61/61/61 62/62/62 63/63/63 64/64/64
>
> ...

exported order :

> 130921 vertex positions
>
> v  -0.111804 -0.25702 0.282297
>
> v  -0.110387 -0.261969 0.278314
>
> v  -0.103693 -0.262174 0.281221
>
> v  -0.10503 -0.257238 0.285222
>
> v  -0.10243 -0.267136 0.27725
>
> v  -0.095897 -0.267675 0.280051
>
> v  -0.097084 -0.262695 0.284046
>
> v  -0.098237 -0.25754 0.287812
>
> v  -0.112767 -0.251395 0.285155
>
> v  -0.1062 -0.251911 0.288609
>
> v  -0.09934 -0.252212 0.291206
>
> v  -0.113301 -0.245382 0.287103
>
> v  -0.106914 -0.245987 0.290933
>
> v  -0.119279 -0.251091 0.281232
>
> v  -0.119601 -0.244982 0.282834
>
> v  -0.113586 -0.239219 0.288503
>
> ...
>
> f  1/1/1 2/2/2 3/3/3
>
> f  1/1/1 3/3/3 4/4/4
>
> f  2/2/2 5/5/5 3/3/3
>
> f  3/3/3 5/5/5 6/6/6
>
> f  3/3/3 6/6/6 7/7/7
>
> f  4/4/4 3/3/3 7/7/7
>
> f  4/4/4 7/7/7 8/8/8
>
> f  9/9/9 1/1/1 4/4/4
>
> f  9/9/9 4/4/4 10/10/10
>
> f  10/10/10 4/4/4 8/8/8
>
> f  10/10/10 8/8/8 11/11/11
>
> f  12/12/12 9/9/9 10/10/10
>
> f  12/12/12 10/10/10 13/13/13
>
> f  13/13/13 10/10/10 11/11/11
>
> f  14/14/14 1/1/1 9/9/9
>
> f  15/15/15 14/14/14 9/9/9
>
> ...

Comment: In what way does it re-index the vertices? Is there a fixed offset, or are the indices "jumbled"? Keep in mind that obj indices can follow the negative convention - see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file#Vertex_Indices).

Comment: After exporting 3d model the indices are jumbled! I set some landmark on my model before save it. each landmark stores a special vertex index. with jumbled indices the landmarks are useless :'(

Comment: Can you post a *sample* of the exported indices and the *expected* indices, i.e. the corresponding ones in your in-memory mesh object?

Comment: Of course! I did edit my question!

Comment: So you store your models as quads in-memory? No wonder they look "jumbled" in the obj file - Assimp splits each quad into two triangles before exporting. This might naturally require it to re-arrange the vertices.

Comment: I did load exported model and save it again in a new file, but saved vertex indices is not same with loaded one!  loaded faces : f  1/1/1 2/2/2 3/3/3
f  1/1/1 3/3/3 4/4/4
f  2/2/2 5/5/5 3/3/3
f  3/3/3 5/5/5 6/6/6 saved faces : f  1/1/1 2/2/2 3/3/3
f  2/2/2 4/4/4 3/3/3
f  5/5/5 6/6/6 2/2/2
f  5/5/5 2/2/2 1/1/1

Comment: Yes I amended my comment - but that's not the issue here.You are expecting quads whereas Assimp obj's work with tris. Try converting your model to triangles.

Comment: I converted quads to triangles but the problem is not solved! Is there any solution?

Comment: I see from the documentation that the first argument to `ExportFile` is of type `Scene`. Do you have multiple models in `_raw`? If so then that could be the problem - obj concatenates all models into a contiguous file, so indices become mixed. Also, obj applies any transformations on a model to its vertices, so they may be different.

Comment: There is one object in the scene, to ensure that I compared vertex count of original object and exported object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asset-Importer-Lib will do an optimization of the geometry. So we canot guarantee that the order of your vertices will be unchanged.

Comment: So what is the solution?

Comment: What I can think of would be something like a flag to store the ordering. But we need to evaluate if this is possible. When the model will be modified by the post-processing most of the data will be reorganized.

Comment: What we can do is something like organizing your vertices into special g´nodes? What is the reason for you to export the vertices in the same ordering?

Comment: Can you introduce to me a graph node creator tool?